# Goroutines and mutex

Tags: go, goroutine

```
func (s *Server) start() {
         s.Lock()
         defer s.Unlock()
        if !s.isClosed{
           go s.processing()
        }
        go s.start()
 }

func (s *Server) processing() {
  s.Lock()
  // do stuff
  s.Unlock()
}
```

I have a working Golang project that has a block of code following the logic shown above.

I don't understand why this logic works as I would've expected a deadlock.

Comment: Why would you expect it to deadlock?

Comment: Why would you expect a deadlock? What part of the logic don't you understand?

Comment: I expected a deadlock because s is locked in start() and it's trying to lock again in processing() and s hasn't unlocked.

Comment: But it will unlock. `start` isn't blocked on anything, the other calls are concurrent, so it will release the lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll call the initial goroutine that's running when `start` is entered G1.

1. `start` (in G1) locks the mutex and defers the unlock until `start` returns.
2. `start` calls `s.processing` in a new goroutine (G2)
3. `start` calls itself in a new goroutine (G3)
4. `start` (G1) unlocks the mutex and returns.

None of those calls except the lock at Step 1 is a blocking call. *Concurrently*, in G2, `s.processing` waits for `start` to unlock the mutex (which will happen pretty quickly because all `start` does is start a couple goroutines before unlocking the mutex). Also concurrently, in G3, the above 4 steps are performed all over again (on an apparently infinite loop).

There is no point in that logic that could cause a deadlock.

Comment: More of an infinite recursion than an infinite loop, but similar in effect. It should be noted that this process may actually leak go routines, however.

Comment: In code, yes, it *looks* like recursion. However, because the inner call is concurrent and the outer call returns before the inner, it behaves like an infinite loop, not like recursion.